# How to get value of generated Calendar ID and then push it to a variable based on its row index?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**OBJECTIVE**

- Create booking system using Google form, sheets and calendar
- When there is a new submission, calendar event is automatically created.
- Respondent can also edit their submission (Edit form URL).
- When edited, old event will be deleted, and then new event will be created.

**CURRENT PROBLEM**

- When a row is edited, the updateCalendar() function will also loop through the whole data range; deleting event from the first row.

How to make sure that the function just work on a row that is being edited?

This is what the first row of the sheet looks like.

| Timestamp | Email Address | name | Check-in date | Check-out date | Room | No. of people | total day | total | edit URL | Event Conflict | Event ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

**TRIAL & ERROR**

Currently, I am struggling with this piece of code that will:

- Push generated edit URL (from other function) to a variable **urls**
- Push generated event ID to a variable **ids**
- Matching the index of **urls** and **ids**, assign it to a variable **resultIds** and delete.

This is part of the code that will do the above functions

```
var urls = [], ids = [], resultIds = [];
urls.push(values[i][9]); 
ids.push(newEventId);
resultIds.push([values[i][9]?ids[urls.indexOf(values[i][9])]:'']);
```

This is the full function that will update the calendar: (any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance)

```
    function updateCalendar(request) {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow,13);
var values = range.getDisplayValues(); 
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('c_qsk903qma3b8mp5ensa7bvvg4k@group.calendar.google.com');
var urls = [], ids = [], editIds = [];
getConflicts(request);
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  urls.push(values[i][9]); 
  if (request.eventConflict == "conflict" && values[i][12] != "sent") {
    sheet.getRange(lastRow,11).setValue("conflict");
    break;
  } else if (request.eventConflict == "approve" && values[i][12] != "sent") {      
      var newEvent = calendar.createEvent("booked", request.date, request.endTime);
      var newEventId = newEvent.getId().split('@')[0];
      sheet.getRange(lastRow,11).setValue("approve");
      sheet.getRange(lastRow,12).setValue(newEventId);
      ids.push(newEventId);
      break;
    } else if (request.eventConflict == "conflict" && values[i][10] == "approve"  && values[i][12] == "sent") {
      editIds.push([values[i][0]?ids[urls.indexOf(values[i][0])]:'']);
      var eventEditId = calendar.getEventSeriesById(values[i][11]);
      eventEditId.deleteEventSeries();
      sheet.getRange(i+2,11).setValue("");
      sheet.getRange(i+2,13).setValue("");
      getConflicts(request);
      if (request.eventConflict == "approve") {
        var newEvent = calendar.createEvent("booked", request.date, request.endTime);
        var newEventId = newEvent.getId().split('@')[0];
        sheet.getRange(i+2,11).setValue("approve");
        sheet.getRange(i+2,12).setValue(newEventId);
        break;
        } else {
        sheet.getRange(i+2,11).setValue("conflict");
        break;
   } 
  }
}
};
```

[image: For example, 4 submissions are successfully submitted, event for each is created on the connected calendar]

[image: For example, if row 3 is edited (through edit form URL), it will get previous 2 submission instead]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `How can I make sure that the sheet will delete event from the right row`?

Comment: Hi Rafa, thank you for the reply.  What I mean by that statement is that, in current version, the next submission will also delete event from the previous submission (maybe it has something to do with the for() loop. 

So I am trying to figure out how to get the row index in case of respondent editing their own submission (through edit form)

Comment: keep in mind, we do not see the full picture here, perhaps it was enough for Rafa, but to me it's a little unclear what the "previous submission" is (I was in the process of writing the same comment, but stopped when I saw that Rafa posted it). Is it an unrelated event that gets deleted? The last entry in the spreadsheet? Can you provide a sample data set and what gets deleted that should not.

Comment: Hi Vytautas, thank you for the reply, I just added screenshot of: 
1) 4 consecutive new submissions
2) and what happened when I edit submission from the 3rd row.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, didn't have a chance to sit down and look through the code. The for loop seems a little over-engineered as there is a lot going on there that is not really possible to properly understand from someone else looking at the code. I have no way of knowing which if statements would be met when due to the ambigious `request.eventConflict` value that is not defined anywhere in the code. Also, I see that you try to change `getRange(i + 2, 11)` twice, once to a blank value and then again to `approve` or `conflict`. Is that intentional or did you misplace a closing bracket?

Comment: I managed to solve this problem  by using a second sheet in same spreadsheet, and then use e.range method to get edited row index. But thank you for the reply earlier. cheers m8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used two sheets in the same spreadsheet, and then use e.range method to retrieve index of the edited row.  This is the code

```
function updateCalendarTwo(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var responsename = "Main sheet"
  var copyname = "Copy Sheet";
  var responsesheet = ss.getSheetByName(responsename);
  var copysheet = ss.getSheetByName(copyname);
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('Your Calendar ID');
  // columns on copysheet
  var checkInCol = 4;
  var checkOutCol = 5;
  var roomNumCol = 6;
  var appCol = 11
  var eventIDCol = 12;
  var revCol = 14;

  var response = e.range;
  var rRow = response.getRow()

  var rLC = responsesheet.getLastColumn();
  var cLC = copysheet.getLastColumn();
  var rLR = responsesheet.getLastRow();
  var cLR = copysheet.getLastRow();

  if (rLR > cLR){ 
    var resprange = responsesheet.getRange(rLR,1,1,rLC);
    var respdata = resprange.getValues();
    copysheet.appendRow(respdata[0]);
    var eventTitle = copysheet.getRange(rRow,roomNumCol).getValue();
    var startDate = copysheet.getRange(rRow,checkInCol).getValue();
    var endDate = copysheet.getRange(rRow,checkOutCol).getValue().getTime()+ 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    var conflicts = calendar.getEvents(new Date(startDate), new Date(endDate));
    if (conflicts.length < 1) {
    var event = calendar.createAllDayEvent(eventTitle, new Date(startDate), new Date(endDate));
    var eventID = event.getId().split('@')[0];
    copysheet.getRange(rRow,appCol).setValue("approve");
    copysheet.getRange(rRow,eventIDCol).setValue(eventID);
    } else {
    copysheet.getRange(rRow,appCol).setValue("conflict");
    }
  } else {
    var resprange = responsesheet.getRange(rRow,1,1,9);
    var respdata = resprange.getValues();
    var copyrespRange = copysheet.getRange(rRow,1,1,9);
    copyrespRange.setValues(respdata);

    var respAppRange = copysheet.getRange(rRow,appCol);
    var respApp = respAppRange.getValue();

    if (respApp == 'conflict') {
    var eventTitle = copysheet.getRange(rRow,roomNumCol).getValue();
    var startDate = copysheet.getRange(rRow,checkInCol).getValue();
    var endDate = copysheet.getRange(rRow,checkOutCol).getValue().getTime()+ 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    var conflicts = calendar.getEvents(new Date(startDate), new Date(endDate));
    if (conflicts.length < 1) {
      var editedEvent = calendar.createAllDayEvent(eventTitle, new Date(startDate), new Date(endDate));
      var editedEventID = editedEvent.getId().split('@')[0];;
      copysheet.getRange(rRow,appCol).setValue("edited");
      copysheet.getRange(rRow,eventIDCol).setValue(editedEventID);
      } else {
      copysheet.getRange(rRow,appCol).setValue("conflict");
      };
    } else {
      var eventEditId = copysheet.getRange(rRow,eventIDCol).getDisplayValue();
      var editedEvent = calendar.getEventSeriesById(eventEditId);
      editedEvent.deleteEventSeries();
      var eventTitle = copysheet.getRange(rRow,roomNumCol).getValue();
      var startDate = copysheet.getRange(rRow,checkInCol).getValue();
      var endDate = copysheet.getRange(rRow,checkOutCol).getValue().getTime()+ 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
      var conflicts = calendar.getEvents(new Date(startDate), new Date(endDate));
      if (conflicts.length < 1) {
        var editedEvent = calendar.createAllDayEvent(eventTitle, new Date(startDate), new Date(endDate));
        var editedEventID = editedEvent.getId().split('@')[0];;
        copysheet.getRange(rRow,appCol).setValue("edited");
        copysheet.getRange(rRow,eventIDCol).setValue(editedEventID);
        } else {
        copysheet.getRange(rRow,appCol).setValue("conflict");
        };
      };
  
  }
}
```